# "Static plugin" system (via build system) in C++

Tags: c++, project-management, build-process

I am working on a C++ product currently. It was designed to have a fair amount of flexibility and has grown bigger and bigger. Now we are planning to cooperate in a project where we would like to contribute parts of the product: some parts as source code, some parts as static link libraries, some parts not at all.

I would like to keep one version of every source file which is used in both projects and avoid branching the whole thing etc. So I was wondering what I need to be able to have the "full product" internally with all files and also be able to extract a part of these files (every now and then) and pass this subset as a working unit to others. (I assume we can ensure that these files are not changed in the cooperation project, we will only add stuff there.)

I guess I need

- a software architecture that is loosely coupled so that parts can be removed without breaking the system. I think the term "static" plugin is appropriate here because I think I can learn from plugin systems, but I do not need to have the ability to load them dynamically, they can be linked/built in a static way. I hope this could force me and my co-workers to extend the system by adding some kind of a plugin instead of inserting classes here and there, introducing coupling between things.
- a build system that supports me with selecting which plugins to build and "releasing" new subsets by extracting only what I need.

Are there any internet resources that might help. What are the keywords to search for?

Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an interesting article series from Dr Dobbs that you might want to check out. I seem to remember that it supports static linking of plugins in addition to the usual dynamic linking. Check out [Building Your Own Plugin Framework](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/204202899).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Primarily, you need something like git:

https://git-scm.com/

to manage the source. To manage "plugins", static or not, it may pay to look at existing systems that already do this: I can recommend examining how Python does it (since there is a well specified C API for managing it).

The best build system I know of is .. Python. Forget makes :) A prebuilt one is Erick Tryzelaars fbuild (available from github).[Well I think it is the best because I'm using it :]